# How to read a session variable from a php file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, usersession

There have been far too many questions on this subject but I still fail to understand.

Case:

1. Hyperlinked image
2. OnClick of image: Check if session exists
3. If session exist, open link
4. If session does not exist, show login form

`onclick` is calling a JavaScript function:

```
var my_global_link = '';
var check = '<?php echo $_SESSION["logged_in"]; ?>';

function show_login( link ) {

     if(check == 1)
     {
         window.location = link;
     }
     else
     {
         my_global_link = link;  
            // .. then show login modal that uses 'js/whitepaper-login.js'
            document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('fade').scrollIntoView(true); 
     }

}
```

Global variable is being saved in another php file as :

`$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;`

I am unable to capture the session value in the `var check`. Can you advise?

Comment: To use PHP session variables with JavaScript you have to use AJAX to call some PHP that will return the variables or set the JS variables after the session has been started and before PHP outputs the page.

Comment: Please format this line in question  `var check = '<?php echo $_SESSION["logged_in"]; ?>';`

Comment: var check = <?php echo  "'" . $_SESSION['logged_in']; . "';" ?>

Comment: @JayBlanchard can you elaborate on how the variables can be set through AJAX?

Comment: I added a simple example @Sarah

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery here is a simple example of how to get a PHP `$_SESSION` into your JavaScript:

session.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['foo'] = 'foo';
    echo $_SESSION['foo']; // this will be echoed when the AJAX request comes in
?>
```

get_session.html (assumes jQuery has been included)

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('a').click(function(event){ // use instead of onclick()
            event.preventDefault(); // prevents the default click action

            // we don't need complex AJAX because we're just getting some data
            $.get('session.php', function(sessionData) {
                console.log( sessionData ); // session data will be 'foo'
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<a href="session.php">click</a>
```

If this is successful you'll see the data and can use it in other JavaScript functions by passing the data appropriately. I often find it handy to `json_encode()` session data, returning JSON to be used by JavaScript, but there is no need to in a simple example such as this one.

Comment: The `session.php` for me is a file that is being called when the login is clicked initially and the data is posted via ajax. In this case, I am calling session.php directly which is actually whats setting the session variable. What if the variable has not been set? Wouldnt calling `session.php` set the variable?

Comment: I'd have to see the code for your session.php @Sarah Are you including that file in the one you show above?

Answer (score 1):

Make the request to someone file.php

```
$( document ).ready(function(){//run when DOM is loaded
  $.post("file.php",  //make request method POST to file.php
     function(data){  //callback of request is data
      var arr = jQuery.parseJSON(data); //make json decoding
      if(arr.logged == 1)   //arr.logged is value needs
       #do 
     })
 })
```

file.php

```
<?php
 session_start(); //start session for my dear friend Jay Blanchard
 $_SESSION['logged_id'] = 1; //init value for example
 $array = array('logged' => $_SESSION['logged_id']);//creat array for encoding
 echo json_encode($array); //make json encoding for call back
?>
```

Comment: Typo: change `logged =>` to `"logged" =>`

Comment: Your session variable will be undefined.

Comment: Global variable is being saved in another php file as :$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;

Comment: I write this cod in accordance with condition

Comment: Read first the condition pls

Comment: The condition requires a `$_SESSION` @AlexandruGojinetchi. If you do not use `session_start()` your session variable in file.php is not available.

Comment: lol  @JayBlanchard Blanchard .This's just section of all code(section answering the question),or you want ,to open $_SESSION and close ??,if so, I want to tell you that you have not closed all the session

Comment: It isn't about opening and closing sessions @AlexandruGojinetchi, it is about helping the user with code that will work. As it stands your PHP code will not work. You cannot make assumption that the OP will know everything they need to do.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Blanchard How do you, the user asks how to take value using js, and I do to write have to open and close session

Answer (score 0):

your javascript is not a very good solution, as it can be hacked easily. One can simply change the value of `check` to whatever one likes, and even without a login one would be able to access the link of the picture.

A better implementation would probably be something like:

```
<a href="checklogin.php"><img src="img.png" alt="" /></a>
```

checklogin.php would then verify the `$_SESSION` variable. If validated, you can use `header("Location: something.html");` to redirect to where you want to bring the user. If not logged in, you can instead redirect to the login page: `header("Location: login.php");`

Answer (score 0):

@Sarah 
You have to first call the php file via ajax and set the javascript variable as the result. Since the javascript is a client side scripting language hence it can't read server side PHP script.
Hence on click call javascript function

```
function someFunc(){
    //Fire Ajax request 
    //Set check variable 
    //and perform the function you want to ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php include "sess.php"; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var my_global_link = 'testr.com';
var check = '<?php echo $_SESSION["logged_in"]; ?>';

function show_login( link ) {

 if(check == 1)
 {
     window.location = link;
 }
 else
 {
     my_global_link = link;  

        document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('fade').scrollIntoView(true); 
     }

    }

     </script> 
    <a href="#" onclick="show_login('test')" >test</a>
```

file1.php

```
   <?php 
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["logged_in"] = 1;
   ?>
```

sess.php

I have done this using two files. You may have not included session file I guess. Its working fine for me.

Comment: what is in the `sess.php` file?

Comment: I made a file sess.php where i started the session and set the session variable $_SESSION['logged_in'] . I included this file in the main file where your code is.